# most efficient way to find a path between 2 nodes in a grid

Tags: java, algorithm, path-finding

i have always been curious on how this particular problem is best solved. The closes thing i could find to my problematic was the pipeline game concept,[see screenshot](http://www.passionforpuzzles.com/blog/uploaded-images-2008/plumber-puzzle-game.jpg)

i have a grid of 10x10. every rectangle of the grid can connect to the adjacent fields with 1 to 4 edges (no diagonals, just top,bot,left,right) on the left side of the grid there can be 10 starting points, one on each row, and on the right 10 end points also 1 in each row of the grid.

Now my question: what is the most efficient way to find all the possible paths from the starting point to any of the end points and also all the dead-end paths (the path that has a couple of points connected to the starting point but doesn't connect to any of the end points)?

I have tried the breadth-first search algorithm to find all the paths between them, but is there any better alternatives i could try out?

Comment: Why are you looking for an alternative?

Comment: The other natural alternative is the depth-first search.  Yet, I agree with @svick in asking why you need an alternative.

Comment: I am exploring all the possibilities, mostly i am just curious of what is available out there that targets this problematic. and how about the dead ends. it is safe to assume that the best way would be to find a path starting from each of the squares to at least one of the starting points?

Comment: with this format of grid it sounds like you don't need BFS/DFS at all since the algorithm to find the shortest track between two points is simple (just go right until you're above/below the next point and then go down/up respectively).

Comment: `what is the most efficient way to find all the possible paths` There are inifnite number of paths between any two points on the grid... concider `left->right->left->right....` so it will be hard to find **all paths**... You should restrict yourself to shortest path or at most k shortest paths, for a constant k

Comment: @amit, when searching for all paths, usually only simple paths (i.e. with no repeated vertices) are considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) is much faster then BFS, for finding **shortest path** on a graph.

A* requires you to have an [admissible heuristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) [the [manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) heuristic can usually be applied on a grid], and is usually much faster then BFS, since it is informed - so it preferes investigating nodes which are more likely to lead to a better solution.

Note that A* is also complete [finds a path if there is one] and also optimal [finds the shortes path].

**EDIT:**

A* also allows more trade off of time/performance: for example: By using a [weighted A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Weighted_A.2A), you will get a non-optimal solution, but you are likely to get it much faster.

Note that for uninformed A* [`h=0`] by invoking A* you get a dijkstra, which is exactly BFS for non-weighted edges

Comment: yes A* coupled with an appropriate heuristic perform extremely well

Comment: The question doesn't talk about shortest paths at all. Because of this, I think it doesn't make any sense to use A*.

Comment: This is exactly why I explicitly mentioned A* is good for finding **shortest path**.

Answer (score 1):

If you start breadth-first, you are collecting paths first of length 1, then 2, 3, 4 and so on. In the next step from length k to k+1, you add an end point to some path only, when the end point is not used already in some path. That guarantees you discard less or equally optimal paths.

Beside the origin, all path points have a definite incoming edge. Hence as data structure one could store the incoming edge (or no_incoming) per point.
This discards equally optimal paths.

***Case: with equally optimal paths***
Equally optimal paths could be represented in the data as a point having several incoming edges.
Going from length k to k+1 all the new end-points are collected.

- If a candidate end-point exists in the paths but not in the new (k+1) long end-points, it is a suboptimal path, and is dropped. Recursion fails.
- If a candidate end-point is fresh, a new optimal path is found. Recursion continues.
- If a candidate end-point only exists in the new end-points, an alternative optimal path is found. Recursion stops too.

---

***A bit of code***

```
public void determineAllPaths(Grid grid, Point origin) {
    this.grid = grid;
    this.origin = origin;
    grid.setOnPath(origin, null); // to, from
    Set<Point> priorEndPoints = Collections.singleton(origin);
    determinePaths(priorEndPoints);
}

private void determinePaths(Set<Point> priorEndPoints) {
    if (priorEndPoints.isEmpty())
        return;
    Set<Point> nextEndPoints = new HashSet<Point>();
    for (Point priorEndPoint : priorEndPoints) {
        for (Point nextEndPoint : priorEndPoint.naybours()) {
            if (grid.isOnPath(nextEndPoint)
                    && !nextEndPoints.contains(nextEndPoint)) {
                continue;
            }
            //if (nextEndPoints.contains(nextEndPoint)) {
            //    continue;
            //}
            grid.setOnPath(nextEndPoint, priorEndPoint); // to, from
            nextEndPoints.add(nextEndPoint);
        }
    }
    determinePaths(nextEndPoints);
}
```